# R: dplyr group by date range

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to group a data frame by 3 date ranges based on "2016-04-10" and "2016-04-24".

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16803, 16810, 16817, 16824, 
16831, 16838, 16845, 16852, 16859, 16866, 16873, 16880, 16887, 
16894, 16901, 16908, 16915, 16922, 16929, 16936, 16943), class = "Date"), 
    new = c(1507L, 2851L, 3550L, 5329L, 7557L, 5546L, 6264L, 
    7160L, 9468L, 5789L, 5928L, 4642L, 8145L, 4867L, 4846L, 5231L, 
    7137L, 3938L, 3741L, 2937L, 194L), resolved = c(21, 27, 15, 
    16, 56, 2773, 8490, 8748, 9325, 7734, 10264, 6739, 6110, 
    9613, 10314, 10349, 7200, 9637, 10831, 11170, 5666), ost = c(1486, 
    2824, 3535, 5313, 7501, 2773, -2226, -1588, 143, -1945, -4336, 
    -2097, 2035, -4746, -5468, -5118, -63, -5699, -7090, -8233, 
    -5472)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), .Names = c("date", "new", "resolved", "ost"))
```

Tried the following:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(dr=cut(date,breaks=as.Date(c("2016-04-10","2016-04-24")))) %>%
                summarise(ost = sum(ost))
```

Which gives the wrong result as below.

```
        dr    ost
2016-04-10 -10586
        NA -17885
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: If you look at the `cut` output, only some of the observation fall in the category, otherwise, all are NAs

Comment: `df %>% group_by(dr = cut(date, breaks = c(min(date), as.Date(c("2016-04-10", "2016-04-24")), max(date) + 1))) %>% summarise(ost = sum(ost))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a grouping variable first,

```
df %>% 
mutate(group = cumsum(grepl('2016-04-10|2016-04-24', date))) %>%
group_by(group) %>% 
summarise(ost = sum(ost))

#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#  group    ost
#  (int)  (dbl)
#1     0   8672
#2     1 -10586
#3     2 -26557
```

Comment: You can add the `group` column inline with `mutate(group = cumsum(grepl('2016-04-10|2016-04-24', df$date)))`

Comment: thanks @Sotos. it works! Would you mind explaining how cumsum works to create the groups?

Comment: @woshishui by using `grepl` you create a logical vector. Cumulative sum just adds the values of that vector with FALSE = 0 and TRUE = 1.

Answer (score 10):

We create a grouping variable 'dr' with `cut`.  The `breaks` mentioned are the `range` of the 'date' i.e. the `min` and `max` values of the 'date' along with the dates specified by the OP, concatenate it (`c`), use the option `include.lowest` and get the `sum` of 'ost' based on this grouping variable.

```
df %>%
  group_by(dr = cut(date, breaks = c(range(date), 
            as.Date(c("2016-04-10", "2016-04-24"))), include.lowest=TRUE) ) %>% 
  summarise(ost =sum(ost))
#         dr    ost
#     <fctr>  <dbl>
#1 2016-01-03   8672
#2 2016-04-10 -10586
#3 2016-04-24 -26557
```

Or another option is `findInterval` which could be faster compared to `cut`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(dr = findInterval(date, as.Date(c("2016-04-10", "2016-04-24")))) %>% 
  summarise(ost = sum(ost))
#     dr    ost
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1     0   8672
#2     1 -10586
#3     2 -26557
```

NOTE: The OP asked the question about `cut` and this solution gives that.

Comment: can you please explain the first one ? here is what I thought  at first you pass the df to group_by using %>% then there are two arguments for group_by which converts the df into groups. inside the group_by you use cut to change numeric into factor which cut(x, breaks,include.lowest = TRUE) . x is the date (because we want to have the data grouped by date , breaks is giving the interval that date is going to be cut. I don't know why then you use as.Date  and include.lowest=TRUE means if date is lowest then should be used for breaks .

Comment: then the output of this will pass to the new function by again %>% and summarise(ost = sum(ost)) shows the sum of out column. did I understood correctly ?

Comment: Sure, I will add the descriptio

Comment: thanks ! I like your post, I am going to read all your valuable solution you have given to people, I think it helps me a lot

Comment: @Learner the `%>%` is a pipe or chain operator which connects the lhs with the rhs.  I used `as.Date` because we are passing two more date elements as `character` vector.  The `include.lowest` is `FALSE` by default.   According to documentation `logical, indicating if an ‘x[i]’ equal to the lowest (or highest, for right = FALSE) ‘breaks’ value should be included`.

Comment: Thanks akrun, especially for pointing out the findInterval function.